# How can I stop the camera from switching back to the launcher?

Tags: camera

I am trying to use my camera to record some videos. I have it set up on the tripod and then go and set up whatever I'm shooting and after 2 minutes, the camera always exits and goes back to the launcher screen. So I have to restart the camera again, and then re-do whatever settings I had (like zoom in again). Is there a way to have the camera app just stay open without automatically closing? Thanks.

Edit: I'm using a Samsung Galaxy 7 with the latest OS. And I'm referring to the built-in camera app. (If there's a better alternative, I'd be glad to hear it. I've seen reviews of several but nothing that seemed compelling enough to try.)

Comment: And which camera app? Maybe try [an alternative](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera)? (Disclosure: Link goes to my site)

Comment: Wow @Izzy, that's comprehensive! It'll take me a while to read through all that.

Comment: Enjoy! My recommendations are pointed out clearly. One of them was already picked by @beeshyams [in his answer](/a/179689/16575) – clearly my favorite (I use it myself, of course).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/179689/96277) from beeshyams, if you cannot afford to replace your preferred camera app than try [screen pinning](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6118421) that app.

> You can pin an app's screen to keep it in view until you unpin it.
>
> For example, you can pin an app and hand your phone to a friend. With the screen pinned, your friend can use only that app. To use your other apps again, you can unpin the screen.

Alternatively, you can use a [kiosk-mode](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=kiosk&c=apps) app from Play Store to temporarily restrict usage of the device to your camera app.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Izzy's list of  [camera apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_camera)

[Open Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sourceforge.opencamera) is an excellent *ad - free (FOSS),  open source* camera app which has a timer that can be set from **upto 5 minute delay** for both camera and video. And it has voice command activation too !

Other features quoting Izzy

> - Developer is Almalence, known from a set of high quality camera apps (a specialist in this area) which are also available in "free trials" and paid versions on the Playstore.
> - The "full program" would be [A Better Camera](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.almalence.opencam_plus),  which combines his Night Camera, HDR Camera and more ( you can read in reviews and tutorials on Izzy's description )

This app is available at huge discount now !

Tested it and this should solve your problem. Of course, you can try other apps on that list as well